# Awk match() - multiple per line

Tags: regex, shell, awk, match, gawk

I'm using the match() function in gawk to grab links out of an HTML file.. the regular expression is something like this:

```
match($0, /(<a href=\")([^\"]+)/, arr)
```

I don't seem to be able to use the "/g" option at the end to get multiple matches per line though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct. AWK regular expressions don't have flags.
Also, there's no built-in support for having `match` look for the second or later matches.
Only the `gsub` and `gensub` functions have that.
I'd try something like this:

```
gensub(/.*<a href=\"([^\"]+)/, "\1%", "g")
last = split($0, "%", arr)
delete arr[last]
```

where `%` is a string that you can guarantee won't be found in the input.

Answer (score 1):

The text-mode browser lynx might be a better tool for harvesting URLs. It's `-dump` flag writes formatted output to standard output. At the end, you'll find a numbered list of every visible and hidden link on that page. (Or file. It accepts URLs or filenames as arguments.)

```
$ lynx -dump http://www.stackoverflow.com 

[snip]
References

   Visible links
   1. http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml
   2. http://stackoverflow.com/feeds
   3. http://stackexchange.com/
   4. http://stackoverflow.com/users/login
   5. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/
   6. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/
[snip]
 676. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 677. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

   Hidden links:
 678. http://www.peer1.com/stackoverflow
 679. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
```